# Illegal instruction anaconda3

Tags: raspberry-pi, anaconda, raspberry-pi4

I tried to install anaconda on raspberry pi 4 and when I type command

`./Anaconda3-2021.11-Linux-aarch64.sh`

the output being as follow:

> PREFIX=/home/pi/anaconda3
> Unpacking payload
> ... Illegal instruction

Note: The OS of raspberry is aarch64

Comment: Close voting as off-topic - consider posting to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com